# has anyone tried wambam no dig fence

Tags: fence

I need to replace 3 fence panels and posts and i can't find any contractor, i am guessing because it is a small job. The only contractor i was able to find wants $1500 without staning or hauling away the old fence which is more than i expected.

I found that there is a no dig wambam vinyl fence system. I ordered sample but i am curious if anyone here has any experience with this.

The main reason i am going this route is so that i can avoid digging and mixing cement. Also i couldn't find any pre-made 7ft wooden tranditional panels. 3 panels i have are made of 8ftx2 and one 5.5ft so i need to replace 21.5 linear ft. WamBam happen to have 7ft fence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no set reason that you have to use cement to set the posts into the holes. In many instances it can be effective to simply dig the post holes, set the post into position and then dribble the dirt back into the hole and tamp it in with a length of 2x2 or 2x4 to pack the soil in place around the post.

In my farming days past we built lots of fences this way. It does not work well initially if the soil is too wet or too fine grained sand.